# Problem choosing an equation for a NLS model I need to present academically

Tags: r, equation, nls

I want to be able to predict the optical density of a radiograph (x-ray image) based on the input factors of depth, SID, KVP, MAS. I'm a lot more familiar with linear models and have never had to give a model an equation before, and frankly, I have no idea what the equation should be.

I've used the equation below and the model is successful and does fit well (to an extent) with the experimental data, so it does what I need to do. However, I want to choose an equation the 'proper' way however that might be as I want to present my research academically. I can find little to no guidance on this however online.

```
sa1<-nls(OD~ ((KVP^a)*(MAS^b))/((SID^c)*(e*DEPTH^d)),
         data=bathdata,
         start=c(a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0.1, e=0.1))
```

For reference OD increases>
exponentially with increasing MAS

exponentially with increasing KVP

AND

OD decreases>
exponentially with increasing SID
exponentially with increasing depth

[I'm an undergrad student trying to model OD as part of a project to optimise images and thus reduce radiation dose to bariatric patients]

Thank you for any responses

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kerry.  You may get better answers to this question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Dave I'll give it a go on there

Comment: The equation you have would be much more stable to estimate if you logged it: `log(OD) = a * log(KVP) + b * log(MAS) - c * log(SID) - d * log(e * DEPTH)`. After logging all the variables, it's now a linear equation you could use `lm` to fit (except for the `e` parameter).